# Positioning text a center of Layout

Tags: qml

I am working on some software using [Qt 5.7](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/index.html) and I have simple [Rectangle](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html#details) containing custom `Button` and [Text](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qml-qtquick-text.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window
{
    width: 1024
    height: 768

    visible: true

    Rectangle
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        color: "#e4e4e4"

        border.width: 0
        border.color: "#e4e4e4"

        radius: 32

        ColumnLayout
        {
            anchors.fill: parent

            spacing: 8

            RowLayout
            {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.minimumHeight: parent.height/2
                Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height/2
                Layout.maximumHeight: parent.height/2

                Rectangle
                {
                    id: buttonBack

                    property bool isPressed: false

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter
                    Layout.minimumWidth: 128
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 128
                    Layout.maximumWidth: 128
                    Layout.minimumHeight: 128
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 128
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 128

                    color: "transparent"

                    Image
                    {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent

                        horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
                        verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter

                        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

                        sourceSize.width: 128
                        sourceSize.height: 128

                        smooth: true

                        antialiasing: true

                        source: (buttonBack.isPressed===true)?"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconarchive/red-orb-alphabet/256/Letter-A-icon.png"
                                                             :"http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i14559/iconarchive/red-orb-alphabet/Arrow.ico"
                    }   // Image

                    MouseArea
                    {
                        anchors.fill: parent

                        onPressed:
                        {
                            buttonBack.isPressed=true;
                        }   // onPressed

                        onPressAndHold:
                        {

                        }   // onPressAndHold

                        onReleased:
                        {
                            buttonBack.isPressed=false;
                        }   // onReleased

                        onClicked:
                        {
                        }   // onClicked
                    }   // MouseArea
                }   // Rectangle

                Text
                {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

                    color: "black"

                    text: qsTr("TEST TEXT")

                    font.pointSize: 24
                }   // Text
            }   // RowLayout
        }   // RowLayout
    }   // Rectangle
}   // Window
```

The problems is the text "**Test Text**" is not horizontally aligned at center of screen becuase it has neighbour (button). How do I center this text horizontally regardless of neighbour Button? Here is screenshot of problem:
[image: Text misaligned]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use layouts if you want to place your items with absolute position. Use anchors instead:

```
Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Rectangle
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#e4e4e4"
        border.width: 0
        border.color: "#e4e4e4"
        radius: 32
        ColumnLayout
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 8
            Item {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Rectangle
                {
                    id: buttonBack
                    color: "transparent"
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    Image
                    {
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        sourceSize.width: 128
                        sourceSize.height: 128
                        smooth: true
                        antialiasing: true
                        source: (buttonBack.isPressed===true)?"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconarchive/red-orb-alphabet/256/Letter-A-icon.png"
                                                             :"http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i14559/iconarchive/red-orb-alphabet/Arrow.ico"
                    }   // Image
                }   // Rectangle

                Text
                {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    color: "black"
                    text: qsTr("TEST TEXT")
                    font.pointSize: 24
                }   // Text
            }
        }   // RowLayout
    }   // Rectangle
}
```

[image]

Comment: So, this task is impossible to solve using Layouts?

Comment: Layouts allows you to arrange each item according the others and the available space. You can play with the margins to recenter the text. But, it's not a good idea, imho...